# GraphQL placeOrder gives Integrity constraint violation in `quote_shipping_rate`

Tags: magento2, checkout, graphql, place-order, shipping-rates

I am trying to place order with the below mutation, but getting  `Integrity constraint violation` error for `address_id` in saving `quote_shipping_rate`.

I assume the old shipping rate is not getting deleted in the transaction flow, but I tried loading by collection in `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Addres\Rate->beforeSave()` which give **zero** results in same place order flow.

Magento Version: 2.4.5-p3

PHP: 8.1.16

GraphQL Request:

```
mutation PaymentOptionsAndPlaceOrder($cartId: String!) {
  setPaymentMethodOnCart(
    input: {cart_id: $cartId, payment_method: {code: "checkmo" }}
  ) {
    cart {
      id
      selected_payment_method {
        code
        title
        purchase_order_number
        __typename
      }
      shipping_addresses {
        selected_shipping_method {
          carrier_code
          method_code
          method_title
          carrier_title
          amount {
            currency
            value
            __typename
          }
          __typename
        }
        available_shipping_methods {
          carrier_code
          method_code
          price_incl_tax {
            currency
            value
            __typename
          }
          price_excl_tax {
            currency
            value
            __typename
          }
          __typename
        }
        __typename
      }
      prices {
        __typename
        applied_taxes {
          amount {
            currency
            value
            __typename
          }
          label
          __typename
        }
        discounts {
          amount {
            currency
            value
            __typename
          }
          label
          __typename
        }
        grand_total {
          currency
          value
          __typename
        }
        subtotal_excluding_tax {
          currency
          value
          __typename
        }
        subtotal_including_tax {
          currency
          value
          __typename
        }
        subtotal_with_discount_excluding_tax {
          currency
          value
          __typename
        }
      }
      items {
        uid
        prices {
          price {
            currency
            value
            __typename
          }
          discounts {
            amount {
              currency
              value
              __typename
            }
            __typename
          }
          __typename
        }
        quantity
        product {
          uid
          name
          sku
          __typename
        }
        __typename
      }
      applied_coupons {
        code
        __typename
      }
      __typename
    }
    __typename
  }
  placeOrder(input: {cart_id: $cartId}) {
    order {
      order_number
      __typename
    }
    __typename
  }
}
```

Error Response:

```json
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "debugMessage": "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db`.`quote_shipping_rate`, CONSTRAINT `QUOTE_SHIPPING_RATE_ADDRESS_ID_QUOTE_ADDRESS_ADDRESS_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`address_id`) REFERENCES `quote_address` (`address_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE), query was: INSERT INTO `quote_shipping_rate` (`carrier`, `carrier_title`, `code`, `method`, `method_description`, `price`, `method_title`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
            "message": "Internal server error",
            "extensions": {
                "category": "internal"
            },
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 124,
                    "column": 3
                }
            ],
            "path": [
                "placeOrder"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "data": {
        "setGuestEmailOnCart": {
            "cart": {
                "email": "milind7@live.com"
            }
        },
        "setPaymentMethodOnCart": {
            "cart": {
                "id": "XOJkOGPzyrSXAx0hk01A0wq2S9LBASdu",
                "selected_payment_method": {
                    "code": "checkmo",
                    "title": "Check / Money order",
                    "purchase_order_number": null,
                    "__typename": "SelectedPaymentMethod"
                },
                "shipping_addresses": [
                    {
                        "selected_shipping_method": {
                            "carrier_code": "flatrate",
                            "method_code": "flatrate",
                            "method_title": "Fixed",
                            "carrier_title": "Flat Rate",
                            "amount": {
                                "currency": "USD",
                                "value": 5,
                                "__typename": "Money"
                            },
                            "__typename": "SelectedShippingMethod"
                        },
                        "available_shipping_methods": [
                            {
                                "carrier_code": "flatrate",
                                "method_code": "flatrate",
                                "price_incl_tax": {
                                    "currency": "USD",
                                    "value": 5,
                                    "__typename": "Money"
                                },
                                "price_excl_tax": {
                                    "currency": "USD",
                                    "value": 5,
                                    "__typename": "Money"
                                },
                                "__typename": "AvailableShippingMethod"
                            }
                        ],
                        "__typename": "ShippingCartAddress"
                    }
                ],
                "prices": {
                    "__typename": "CartPrices",
                    "applied_taxes": [],
                    "discounts": null,
                    "grand_total": {
                        "currency": "USD",
                        "value": 45,
                        "__typename": "Money"
                    },
                    "subtotal_excluding_tax": {
                        "currency": "USD",
                        "value": 40,
                        "__typename": "Money"
                    },
                    "subtotal_including_tax": {
                        "currency": "USD",
                        "value": 40,
                        "__typename": "Money"
                    },
                    "subtotal_with_discount_excluding_tax": {
                        "currency": "USD",
                        "value": 40,
                        "__typename": "Money"
                    }
                },
                "items": [
                    {
                        "uid": "Mw==",
                        "prices": {
                            "price": {
                                "currency": "USD",
                                "value": 40,
                                "__typename": "Money"
                            },
                            "discounts": null,
                            "__typename": "CartItemPrices"
                        },
                        "quantity": 1,
                        "product": {
                            "uid": "Mg==",
                            "name": "Test",
                            "sku": "Test",
                            "__typename": "SimpleProduct"
                        },
                        "__typename": "SimpleCartItem"
                    }
                ],
                "applied_coupons": null,
                "__typename": "Cart"
            },
            "__typename": "SetPaymentMethodOnCartOutput"
        },
        "placeOrder": null
    }
}
```

Comment: any solution on this #milind-singh #ahmad